# Как из JavaScript ПОСЛЕДОВАТЕЛЬНО вызвать два серверных REST - метода?

Tags: javascript, ajax, rest, axios

У меня возникает такая проблема.

Есть одностраничное приложение, которое работает с сервером, дёргая по REST разные серверные методы.
В какой то момент мне понадобилось по событию (например, нажатию кнопки на странице) вызвать два метода, но последовательно:

данные, которые вернет первый метод, нужно передать во второй.

Вызов REST я делаю через axios, и вызов выглядит так:

```
    axios.post('/api/method1/', $.param(state1))
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('on /api/method1/ response:' + JSON.stringify(response));
            ... // код использующий данные method1
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Error in request: /api/method1/');
        });
```

Вызов другого серверного метода такой же, с точностью до названия метода.

Если я просто напишу последоваетльно два вызова в JS, то клиент быстренько вызовет первый серверный метод, не дожидаясь ответа - вызовет второй серверный метод, и будет спокойно ждать, кто первый ответит.

А мне надо чтобы был вызов первого метода, постоять, подождать, пока ответит сервер, выполнить еще кусочек кода, который использует эти данные, а потом вызвать второй серверный метод.

Я не могу объединить два метода на сервере, потому что те данные, которые передаются во второй метод, могут быть изменены на клиентской стороне. Так что решение "объединить на сервере два вызова в один" не подходит.

Единственное, что приходит в голову - это "написать второй вызов внутри первого":

```
    axios.post('/api/method1/', $.param(state1))
        .then((response) => {
            console.log('on /api/method1/ response:' + JSON.stringify(response));
            ... // код использующий данные method1

            axios.post('/api/method2/', $.param(state2))
                .then((response) => {
                    console.log('on /api/method2/ response:' + JSON.stringify(response));
                    ... // код использующий данные method2

                })
                .catch((error) => {
                    console.log(error);
                    alert('Error in request: /api/method2/');
                });

        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);
            alert('Error in request: /api/method1/');
        });
```

Но этот вариант мне не нравится - потому, что на практике это приведет к очень большому дублированию кода:
сейчас у меня каждый вызов серверного метода в JS оформлен как отдельная функция, и я могу их вызвать последовательно, просто написав один вызов после другого.

Причем, в некотрых случаях мне надо вызывать method2 после method1, а иногда - method3 после method1.

В случае же, если я начинаю в JS - коде объединять вызовы - мне придётся предусмотреть все возможные сочетания "парных" вызовов.

Ну должен же быть способ сделать из асинхронного кода обратно синхронный?

Спасибо заранее.

Comment: `каждый вызов серверного метода в JS оформлен как отдельная функция` я правильно понимаю, что есть функция типа call_api_method1(arg1, arg2, ...) которая вызывает `axios.post('/api/method1')` и не ждет результат? И вы хотите, чтоб после получения результата с сервера, выполнить следующий шаг, но при этом, чтобы это не было частью реализации `call_api_method1` (т.е. чтоб `call_api_method1` не знал ничего про то будет или не будет сделан следующий шаг и в чем он заключается)?

Comment: Да, Роман, я хотел именно так. После того, как мне в ответе Aziz Umarov подсказал, что у axios может быть "цепочка вызовов" - я стал менять свой код, чтобы сделать именно так. То есть, я понял, что никакой простой возможности "постоять и подождать" нет, и надо всё свести просто к другой модели выполнения кода. Если такая возможность есть - было бы любопытно.

Comment: Я тут подумал, и понял, что в общем виде мой вопрос такой: "как сделать синхронную обертку для асинхронной функции"

Comment: Вот этот момент про `синхронную обертку` непонятен. Что именно имеется ввиду? Чтобы обертка не возвращала управление пока не закончится асинхронный вызов?

Comment: "Чтобы обертка не возвращала управление пока не закончится асинхронный вызов?" - да, именно так. Но это не очень важно, просто пришла в голову более общая формулировка вопроса. Мне самому приходит в голову ответ: 0) завести глобальную переменную, 1) перед асинхронным вызовом записать туда значение!=null 2) после выполнения асинхронного вызова повисать в цикле, не выходя из него, пока значение!=null 3) делать присваивание значение=null по окончанию асинхронного вызова. Но это как то тупо.

Comment: Мой последний план не удался - при попытке реализовать цикл, который будет ожидать изменений флага, который изменится после ответа сервера - браузер просто зависает, загружая все ядра процессора. Всё таки js - мощная штука! жалко только, функции sleep в нём нет, так было бы удобно... Понятно, что ответ лежит где то в области async-await, но мне не удаётся написать код, который бы работал последовательно. Всё вызывается одновременно, немотря на async-await'ы

Answer (score 2):

Пожоже, ответ оказался довольно прост.

Видимо, это единственный путь, и он заключается в том, чтобы во всём коде перейти на async-await.

Для меня было неожиданностью, что при этом ВСЕ функции должны быть помечены как async, иначе это вызывает ошибку 'Uncaught SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function'

Тогда мой код для двух последовательных вызовов стал выглядеть приблизительно так:

```
    async function GetDataFromServer1(arg1){
        
        var tmp_json = { "arg1" : arg1 };
        var tmp = {};
        tmp.text = JSON.stringify(tmp_json);
        
        var response = await axios.post('/api/method1/', $.param(tmp));
        
        return response;
    }


    async function GetDataFromServer2(arg2){
        
        var tmp_json = { "arg2" : arg2 };
        var tmp = {};
        tmp.text = JSON.stringify(tmp_json);
        
        var response = await axios.post('/api/method2/', $.param(tmp));
        
        return response;
    }

    async function on_load {
        var response1 = await GetDataFromServer1(1);
        // ... - здесь может быть произвольный код, формирующий arg2
        var response2 = await GetDataFromServer2(arg2);
    }
```

(Причем, видите, значительную часть этого кода - по три строки в каждой из двух процедур - занимает подготовка данных в нужном для передачи формате. Иначе - код можно было бы сделать еще короче)

Спасибо всем, кто обратил внимание на вопрос и помог советами!

Answer (score 0):

Почему вы создаете call back hell когда манипулируете Promise

```
axios.post('/api/method1/', $.param(state1))
        .then((response) => {
             console.log('on /api/method1/ response:' + 
             JSON.stringify(response));
             ... // код использующий данные method1   
            return axios.post('/api/method2/', $.param(state2));
        })
        .then((responce2) => {
            console.log('on /api/method2/ response:' + 
            JSON.stringify(response2));
                ... // код использующий данные method2 
        })
        .catch((error) => {
            console.log(error);            
        });
```

Comment: я и не знал, что я таким манипулирую. Я нашел пример того, как использовать axios для вызова серверного метода. Стал им пользоваться. все работало прекрасно. Постепенно возникла проблема двух последовательных вызовов, которую я и описал с воём вопросе. И, самое главное, а как Ваш ответ решает описанную проблему? Вы просто задаёте некиу другой вопрос.

Comment: Промисы появились для упрощения жизни. А вы усложняете. Попробуйте изменить и код станет лаконичнее

Comment: "Попробуйте изменить код" - это очень универсальный ответ. К сожалению, он не даёт мне даже направления, в котором нужно двигаться. По Вашему профилю я вижу, что Вы очень опытный разработчик, не могли бы Вы написать немного подробнее, как сделать два последовательных вызова?

Comment: а так понятнее?

Comment: спасибо большое, сейчас попробую.