# асинхронное программирование в js

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs, redux, redux-thunk

пишу социальную сеть на react nodejs, когда захожу в аккаунт в sessionStorage формируется токен,при каждой перезагрузке токен изменяется на рандомную строку. По этому токену запрашиваю из базы, скажем, друзей.Столкнулся с такой проблемой, http запрос происходит до изменения или формирования токена по этому из базы не получаю желаемые данные. Как понимаю нужно организовать асинхронность, пробовал при помощи async/await но не получилось, не понимаю как нужно реализовать задачу

```js
         //компонент

function FriendComponent(props) {

         const [load, setLoad] = useState(true)
        useEffect(()=>{
            if(load == true){
                let key = sessionStorage.currentUser
                //обновляю токен во время перезагрузки
                props.dispatch(loadProfile(key,props.history))
                //загружаю полученные данные из базы
                props.dispatch( updateFriends())
                 setLoad(false)
             }
        })
     console.log(props.friends.friendList);
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <ToolBar/>
   
         <NavBar/>
          <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
          <h4>{props.friends.friendList.length===0?"You don't have any friends":`You have ${props.friends.friendList.length} friends`}</h4>
              <h4 style={props.friends.friendList.length===0?{display:'block'}:{display:'none'}}>You can search for friends <Link to='/profile/search'>here</Link></h4>
            <Paper elevation={3} className='friendlist'>
              {
                props.friends.friendList.map(item=>{
                  return(
                  <Card className={classes.root2} key={item.id}>
                      <CardActionArea>
                        <CardMedia
                          component="img"
                          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
                          height="140"
                          image={`http://localhost:5000/${item.photo}`}
                          title="Contemplative Reptile"
                        />
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                            {item.name} {item.surname}
                          </Typography>
                           
                        </CardContent>
                      </CardActionArea>
                      <CardActions>
                        <Button onClick={()=>props.dispatch(deletaFromFriends(item.id))} size="small" color="primary">
                          delete
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={()=>props.dispatch(goToProfile())} size="small" color="primary">
                          see profile
                        </Button>
                      </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                  )
                })
              }
            
            </Paper>
         </main>
        </div>
  )
};

export default connect(r=>r)(FriendComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Как я понял, Вы хотите обновить токен строго ДО того, как загружать данные.
Я сталкивался с похожей [проблемой](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154114/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-javascript-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%9E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-rest-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Как мне кажется, Вам поможет такая минимальная модификация кода:

```js
         //компонент

async function FriendComponent(props) {

         const [load, setLoad] = useState(true)
        useEffect(()=>{
            if(load == true){
                let key = sessionStorage.currentUser
                //обновляю токен во время перезагрузки
                await props.dispatch(loadProfile(key,props.history))
                //загружаю полученные данные из базы
                props.dispatch( updateFriends())
                 setLoad(false)
             }
        })
     console.log(props.friends.friendList);
    const classes = useStyles();
    
    return (
        <div className={classes.root}>
        <CssBaseline />
        <ToolBar/>
   
         <NavBar/>
          <main className={classes.content}>
          <div className={classes.toolbar}></div>
          <h4>{props.friends.friendList.length===0?"You don't have any friends":`You have ${props.friends.friendList.length} friends`}</h4>
              <h4 style={props.friends.friendList.length===0?{display:'block'}:{display:'none'}}>You can search for friends <Link to='/profile/search'>here</Link></h4>
            <Paper elevation={3} className='friendlist'>
              {
                props.friends.friendList.map(item=>{
                  return(
                  <Card className={classes.root2} key={item.id}>
                      <CardActionArea>
                        <CardMedia
                          component="img"
                          alt="Contemplative Reptile"
                          height="140"
                          image={`http://localhost:5000/${item.photo}`}
                          title="Contemplative Reptile"
                        />
                        <CardContent>
                          <Typography gutterBottom variant="h5" component="h2">
                            {item.name} {item.surname}
                          </Typography>
                           
                        </CardContent>
                      </CardActionArea>
                      <CardActions>
                        <Button onClick={()=>props.dispatch(deletaFromFriends(item.id))} size="small" color="primary">
                          delete
                        </Button>
                        <Button onClick={()=>props.dispatch(goToProfile())} size="small" color="primary">
                          see profile
                        </Button>
                      </CardActions>
                    </Card>
                  )
                })
              }
            
            </Paper>
         </main>
        </div>
  )
};

export default connect(r=>r)(FriendComponent);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/16.6.3/umd/react.production.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-dom/16.6.3/umd/react-dom.production.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: на сколько я помню так выведет ошибку, поскольку, async нужно объявлять той функции внутри которой будит await, вы объявили async на один уровень выше, хоть я и попытался последовать вашему совету отолько объявил  всё вот так

Comment: ```const [load, setLoad] = useState(true)

        useEffect(()=>{if(load == true){

async function asload(){
                let key = sessionStorage.currentUser
               await props.dispatch(loadProfile(key,props.history))
                props.dispatch( updateFriends())
              }
              asload()
                 setLoad(false)
             }
        })
```

Comment: @VahanMuradyan, да, я лажанулся. Просто функция loadProfile() в приведенном коде отсутствует, вот и проглядел :-(

Answer (score 0):

Mожно сделать `async` функцию внутри `useEffect`, и запустить там же.