# На сайте отображается всё количество введённых данные кроме последнего?

Tags: reactjs, golang, frontend, backend

На сайте я ввожу данные, которые отправляются бэкенду `POST`. В базу данных всё нормально записывается. Через `Postman` проверил запрос `GET` бэкенд, туда все данные, хранящиеся в базе данных записывает. Но при получение данных через `GET` во фронтенде возникает баг, например, если я ввожу первый раз имя и фамилию в базу данных то в `console.log()` отображается пустой массив, если я ввожу два раза, то в `console.log()` показывает тот массив, который я ввёл до этого, если три раза, то первые два массива. Могу показать это через видео с экрана, ник в тг @Daniil_Krasnov. Ответ по теме обязательно отмечу решением. Заранее спасибо.
Вот фронтенд:

```
import React, { Component } from "react";
import { NavLink, Link, Route, Switch, Redirect, withRouter } from 'react-router-dom'
import axios from 'axios';
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

class Fighters extends Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      first_name: "",
      last_name: "",
      names:[]
    };
    this.newFighterFirstname = this.newFighterFirstname.bind(this);
    this.newFighterLastname = this.newFighterLastname.bind(this);
    this.saveName = this.saveName.bind(this);
  }

  newFighterFirstname(event) {
    this.setState({first_name : event.target.value})
  }

  newFighterLastname(event) {
    this.setState({last_name  : event.target.value})
  }

  saveName(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    axios(`http://localhost:8000/post`, {
      method: "post", data: {
        first_name: this.state.first_name ,
        last_name: this.state.last_name
      }
    })
    
    axios.get('http://localhost:8000/get')
      .then(rest => {
        console.log(res.data) //вот про этот console.log() я говорю
        this.setState({ names : res.data});
      })
  this.setState({first_name : ""})
  this.setState({last_name  : ""})
  }
  render() {
    const fullname = this.state.names;
    const name = fullname.map((name,index) => 
      <div className="card mt-2">
          <div className="card-body">
              <div key={index} className="btn-group mb-3 " >
                   Боец: {name.first_name} {name.last_name}   
              </div>
           </div>                           
      </div>
     )
    return (

      <div className="container">
        <div className="row">
            <form>
                <div className="form-row">
                    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input type="text"
                        className="form-control" 
                        placeholder="Имя"
                        value={this.state.first_name}
                        onChange={this.newFighterFirstname} />       
                    </div>
                    <div className="form-group col-md-4">
                        <input type="text" 
                        className="form-control"
                        placeholder="Фамилия"
                        value={this.state.last_name}
                        onChange={this.newFighterLastname} />
                    </div>
                     <div className="btn-group ml-4 " >
                        <button className="btn mr-3 btn-secondary"  onClick={this.saveName}>Сохранить</button>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
            <div>
                {name}
            </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
export default Fighters;
```

Вот бэкенд:

```
import (
    "log"
    "net/http"
    "fmt"
    "encoding/json"
    "io/ioutil"
    "database/sql"
    "github.com/gorilla/handlers"
    "github.com/gorilla/mux"
    _ "github.com/lib/pq"
)
type Names struct {
  FirstName  string `json:"first_name"`
  LastName string `json:"last_name"`
}
type Fighter struct {
  FirstName string `json:"first_name"`
  LastName  string `json:"last_name"`
}
func postName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){
  b, err := ioutil.ReadAll(r.Body)
  if err != nil {
    // check err
    }
    var n Names
  if err := json.Unmarshal(b, &n); err != nil {
    // check err
  }
    res, err := json.Marshal(n)
  if err != nil {
    // check err
  }
  w.Header().Set("content-type", "application/json")
    w.Write(res) 
  
    connStr := "user=dan password=1111 dbname=testdb sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    result, err := db.Exec("insert into judges(first_name , last_name) values ($1, $2);", n.FirstName, n.LastName)
    fmt.Println(result.RowsAffected())  // количество добавленных строк
    log.Printf("FirstName: %v , LastName: %v \n", n.FirstName, n.LastName)  // выводит отправленные данные

}
func getName(w http.ResponseWriter,r *http.Request){

    connStr := "user=dan password=1111 dbname=testdb sslmode=disable"
    db, err := sql.Open("postgres", connStr)
    rows, err := db.Query("SELECT * FROM judges")
    if err != nil {
  
  }
  defer rows.Close()

  var fighters = make([]Fighter, 0)
  for rows.Next() {
    var p Fighter
    err := rows.Scan(&p.FirstName, &p.LastName)
    if err != nil {

    }
    fighters = append(fighters, p)
  }
  json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(fighters)
  w.Header().Set("Content-Type", "application/json")
}

func main() {
    fmt.Println("Start")
    router := mux.NewRouter()
   
    router.HandleFunc("/post",postName).Methods("POST")
    router.HandleFunc("/get",getName).Methods("GET")
    fmt.Println("Listen and Server")
    headersOk := handlers.AllowedHeaders([]string{"X-Requested-With", "Content-Type", "Authorization"})
    originsOk := handlers.AllowedOrigins([]string{"http://localhost:8080", "http://localhost:8081", "http://localhost:3000"})
    methodsOk := handlers.AllowedMethods([]string{"GET", "HEAD", "POST", "PUT", "PATCH", "OPTIONS", "DELETE"})
    credentialsOk := handlers.AllowCredentials()
    log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":8000" , handlers.CORS(headersOk, originsOk, methodsOk, credentialsOk)(router)))
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Мне кажется, я знаю, почему.

Смотрите.

Вот функция saveName(). Она делает две вещи: сохраняет данные в базу и запрашивает заново список с сервера.

В коде первая вещь написана над второй, и кажется, что они будут работать последовательно. Но на самом деле из за асинхронной природы js они начинают работать одновременно.

Поэтоум сервер полусчает два запроса:

1. сохрани новое имя
2. верни список имен

Так как операция сохранения требует некоторого времени, то он физически отвечает пользовтелю "старым" список имен, потом делает update, а потом... потом его уже никто ни о чем не спрашивает.

Мне кажется, помогло бы такое переписывание кода клинета:

```
  async saveName(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    await axios(`http://localhost:8000/post`, {
      method: "post", data: {
        first_name: this.state.first_name ,
        last_name: this.state.last_name
      }
    })
    
    await axios.get('http://localhost:8000/get')
      .then(rest => {
        console.log(res.data) //вот про этот console.log() я говорю
        this.setState({ names : res.data});
      })
  this.setState({first_name : ""})
  this.setState({last_name  : ""})
  }
```

Не так давно я задавал подобный [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1154114/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%B8%D0%B7-javascript-%D0%9F%D0%9E%D0%A1%D0%9B%D0%95%D0%94%D0%9E%D0%92%D0%90%D0%A2%D0%95%D0%9B%D0%AC%D0%9D%D0%9E-%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B7%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B4%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D1%81%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%B2%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85-rest-%D0%BC%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B0)

Comment: можно `const res = await axios.` (без `then`)

Comment: a еще лучше get-фазу вынести в функцию, и `useEffect(()=>{ ....get....  },[version])`. т. к. на релоаде и других событиях список тоже должен быть актуальным